# How to verify keyword present in JS script using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

need to verify the keyword `google_conversion_id = 2586489987;` is present in JS script. tried with below code. not able to capture the keyword from JS script. Can one let me how to verify keyword from JS script present in source code?

```
boolean a =driver.getPageSource().contains("2586489987"));
System.out.println(a);
if (a){
  System.out.println("Text  is  Present on page "+driver.getCurrentUrl());
}
else{
  System.out.println("Text  is NOT Present on page "+driver.getCurrentUrl());
  fail =true;
  driver.close();
}
```

JS script is as below. i need to verify `google_conversion_id = 2586489987` is present in JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var google_conversion_id = 9846489987;
  var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
  var google_remarketing_only = true;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the source why not get the real JS value?

```
result = driver.executeScript("return google_conversion_id");
```